# Combine the results of two loops

Tags: loop, plugin-posts-to-posts

I currently have these 2 loops running on a single page

```
$related = p2p_type( 'artist_to_song' )->my_get_related( get_queried_object() );
$features = p2p_type( 'song_to_feature' )->my_get_related( get_queried_object() );


if ( $related->have_posts() ) : 
   while ( $related->have_posts() ) : $related->the_post();
      //content
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();                             
endif;

if ( $features->have_posts() ) : 
   while ( $features->have_posts() ) : $features->the_post();
      //content
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();                             
endif;
```

Is it possible to combine the results of these loops into one so that all the posts are listed in chronological order as opposed to the results of `$related` being followed by `$features`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. First you have to combine the results in one array:

```
$all_posts = array_merge( $related->posts, $features->posts );
```

Now, let's sort the array items by date:

```
usort( $all_posts, function( $a, $b ) {

    return strcmp( $b->post_date, $a->post_date );
} );
```

Finally, do the loop:

```
global $post;
foreach ( $all_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    // use the template tags here: the_title(), the_content(),…
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```